# Formsauthentication for folder does not work on production server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 web application developed on my Win8/VS2012 machine (but using .NET2.0 and not 4.0). I want to protect direct acccess to a number of folders, e.g. the PDF files that are stored in the Content/Documents folder for particular roles, using forms authentication. It works with the below web.config file on my dev machine, and if I type in an URL of a PDF directly, I get redirected to the login page.

However, when copying the whole solution to the production server (windows server 2003R2 sp1, having .NET 2 and 4 installed) the files are directly accessible and it seems as if the forms authentication does not work.

How can I investigate this on the server? 
What is wrong in my config?

Note: the roles are assigned at login time, without a roles provider (as demonstrated by many articles on the internet and on stackoverflow) and I guess I did that correct since it works on my dev machine.

Note 2: One strange thing I noticed is that in the IIS administration tool on the win2003R2 server, the configuration windows do not correspond with what I have in the web.config file. When I right click web app properties in IIS manager, go to ASP.NET tab, go to edit configuration and go to authorization tab for the different locations, it looks like it only states allow * while the config file clearly has deny *. Is it possible that on that server this type of configuration file is not supported (it does not generate any errors either however).

Thx in advance

Wim

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
machine.config.comments usually located in 
\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="..." connectionString="..."  
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="600"/>
  <authentication    mode="Forms">
    <forms name="MYWEBAPP.ASPXAUTH"
           loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           path="/"/>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
  <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>

<location path="Content/Documents"> 
  <system.web>
    <authorization> 
      <allow roles="MEMBER,ADMINISTRATOR"/> 
      <deny users="*"/> 
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Content/Events">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="MEMBER,ADMINISTRATOR"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Content/News">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="MEMBER,ADMINISTRATOR"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Content/PriceChange">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="MEMBER,ADMINISTRATOR"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Administrator">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="MEMBER,ADMINISTRATOR"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Member"> 
  <system.web>
    <authorization> 
      <allow roles="MEMBER,ADMINISTRATOR"/> 
      <deny users="*"/> 
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I remember exactly: does folder with your scripts/webconfg created as application in iis?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your config. Rather, **static files** (jpgs, csses, pdfs) are handled by iis **without** involving asp.net pipeline. This means that your authorization rules are ignored when you ask for a pdf file.

To fix this you can either have an aspx page that gets a parameter that states which file should be downloaded or configure the application to run some (or all) static files through the asp.net pipeline. An easiest way to have **all** requests go through asplnet is to set

```
runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"
```

in the modules section of the web.config.

Comment: The runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests seemed like a good idea, however, I updated the config as below, and added the extra elements, but, the files are still accesible :-(
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>...

Comment: I also did the same update on the production machine and tested there, to make sure it wasn't system dependent, but there also adding the statement to the application's web.config file didn't make any difference.

Even more, I updated web.config to deny all users on the root, and in this scenario I still get the static files, while all dynamic files are redirected to login page... I guess not all request are going throught the ASP.NET pipeline, even if the statement is part of the web.config of the application

Comment: How about putting a local web.config in the pdf folder where the configuration contains only the authorization section? This is better practice than having everything in the global web.config.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem like a good solution to me. I will test now with a aspx page that returns the files from a location that is not directly accessible from the outside... Thx for the response, but a pitty that the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests didn't work.. seemd like the correct solution though